# run JavaScript file in crome console without using html

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, debugging, console

i want to run my JavaScript files directly to separated console or chrome divtools without put it in script tags and using html, just excite it directly from my vs code

i looked for many ways to do that but i wasn't able to find an answer

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how to run it from vs code, but you can always go to dev tools --> sources --> snippets then you can paste your code there and run it.